# How do you show the loading time of an uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if it is possible to display, how long a file has taken to load/upload using just the `form_tag`. Is something like this possible and how do you go about it?

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => :upload }, multipart: true) do %>
<%= file_field_tag :doc %>
<%= submit_tag "upload" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but strictly saying there is no any crossbrowser way to handle it.

HTTP 1.0 either as 1.1 does not have any intermediate response states and progress reports while handling POST request.

This problem might be reduced to file upload speed measurement task.

The most simple way to do it without any plugins is HTML5 FileAPI, but [it's far](http://caniuse.com/fileapi) from crossbrowser state.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861156/ajax-php-upload-file-with-uploading-percentage) could give you all the information you need about your futher workaround.